# Importance of cow, calf & milk during housewarming ceremony

Tags: rituals, cows

While doing housewarming ceremony, what's the significance of the below?

1. Bringing a cow and its calf inside the new home
2. Boiling milk and then let it spill over

Comment: http://www.vasthusastra.com/house_warming.asp  Meanwhile you can see this until someone writes an answer with citing scriptures.

Comment: @AnilKumar thanks for the link! Will take a look at it.

Comment: Giving 100 reputation is an overkill :-). BTW, I have upvoted your question to lessen the damage. When you want to have attention to any of your questions (or even answers), you can simply edit something in it. That will automatically appear on the top according to the SE algorithm. The community is smaller here, hence if you don't get an answer even after few days, it's less likely that any bounty will help. Just IMO.

Comment: I am unable to site any references (as usual), and hence posting this just as a comment.  In one discourse (not sure where or who said) it was explained that cow's output are purifier. This is what panchakavyam means. In those days, every house will typically have a gosala at the rear. So, before constructing the house on the vacant plot the gosala will be constructed at rear and cows will be made to stay. Their output will be made to fall on the plot and make it pure. This practiced cant be practiced today and hence the current practice is adopted symbolically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these rituals are related to VAstushAshtra. According to [this](http://www.puja.net/wordpress/house-warming/) and [this](http://www.vasthusastra.com/house_warming.asp) sources:

Cow and calf are brought to house and the owner garlands them. According to Hindu philosophy, cow is considered to be the home of 330 million gods and by bringing the cow inside the house, it's believed that we invite/offer all the [demi]gods to our house. Above links also relates "cow" as a symbol of Lakshmi or Shiva.

From the various scriptures, like Surabhi, Nadhini, the cow is often symbolized as *[KAmadhenu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamadhenu)*. *Dhenu* stands for cow and *KAm* stands for wishes. Bringing cow inside the house thus relates to wish fulfillment.

Milk here signifies the wealth. Due to its fatty (*snigdha*) nature, it's often categorized as the best *SAtvika* food. In general, milk is offered to God while pooja. Infants get their initial nourishment via milk.

During housewarming, depending on the family traditions, certain people mix rice and milk and feed to the recipients. While certain people spill the milk (as you asked in question) on to the floor as a coolant, similar to how it's offered to *Shivalingam*.